# RDP performance is painfully slow in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

we have a problem with RDP service performance on Ubuntu 22.04LTS desktop version. We are using the Ubuntu machine (modern core i7) as server and access it using MS Remote Desktop client running on a Mac.

RDP performance is painfully slow. UI operations take several seconds to perform. Locally there is no performance issues. Please advice.

If it matters: the desktop is the default "ubuntu" desktop, and rdp service is what came installed as default.

We are not Ubuntu experts, but rather coming from an Apple background.

Thank you.

Comment: The quick answer is "yes it is", or used to be with my experiments years ago. It used to be an RDP wrapper over VNC, but didn't have much of the windows acceleration that makes it work quickly. Does it need to be RDP?

Comment: No, we do not necesasrily need RDP - just a way to graphically administer the Ubuntu machine from a Mac.

Comment: It might be worthwhile looking at an alternative. Https://www.tecmint.com/best-remote-linux-desktop-sharing-software/amp/ for instance. I've used pretty much all the commercial offerings, but some on the list are few. X2go has been operating for years, so might be one to look at, but I've not used it myself